# I can't find a way to access a variable in my html template

Tags: python, django

In my views I am creating a list, called records_list. Inside that list, I have another list in the position [0] and a dictionary in the position [1], as follows:

```
records_list = list()
list_one = Bet.objects.order_by('-game_date')
list_two = {}
```

Inside the "list_two", that is my dictionary, I have a key that is a date "April 2016", for ex, and a value that is a tuple:

```
list_two[aux_month_year] = (aux_wins, aux_losses, aux_voids, s_rate, i_rate, profit)
```

So I return this to my html:

```
records_list.append(list_one)
records_list.append(list_two)
return records_list
```

In the html, I want to create a table, and I start by checking if my profit is positive or not:

```
{% if records_list %}
            <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Wins</th>
                    <th>Losses</th>
                    <th>Void</th>
                    <th>Success Rate</th>
                    <th>Return on Investment</th>
                    <th>Profit</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            {% for key in records_list.1 %}

                {% if records_list.1.key.5 > 0 %}
                    <tr class="success">
                        <td>{{ key }}</td>
                        <td>{{ records_list.1.key.0 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ records_list.1.key.1 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ records_list.1.key.2 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ records_list.1.key.3 }}%</td>
                        <td>{{ records_list.1.key.4 }}%</td>
                        <td>{{ records_list.1.key.5 }}</td>

                    </tr>
```

However, when I try to access `records_list.1.key.5` I get nothing...
This is what happens I get if I `<span>Here: {{ records_list.1}}</span>`:

```
Here: {u'April 2016': (1, 1, 0, 0.0, 125.0, 5.0), 'Total': (1, 1, 0, 0.0, 125.0, 5.0)}Here: {u'April 2016': (1, 1, 0, 0.0, 125.0, 5.0), 'Total': (1, 1, 0, 0.0, 125.0, 5.0)}
```

This is what happens if I `<span>Here: {{ records_list.1.key.5}}</span>`:

```
Here: Here:
```

However, when I access `{{ key }}` I get what is supposed: "April 2016" and "Total"...

Comment: how is list 2 constructed? You could probably `zip` the two lists together to achieve what (I think) you're trying to do but it looks a bit ugly and I'd imagine theres a better alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue using:

```
{% for key, value in records_list.1.items %}
```

and then:

```
{% for key, value in records_list.1.items %}
    {% if value.5 > 0 %}
        <tr class="success">
            <td>{{ key }}</td>
            <td>{{ value.0 }}</td>
            <td>{{ value.1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ value.2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ value.3 }}%</td>
            <td>{{ value.4 }}%</td>
            <td>{{ value.5 }}</td>

        </tr>
```